# How to display different fragment layouts in different weekday?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've created 7 different layouts for 7 fragments and want to show a specific fragment layout in specific day. How can I achieve this.

Comment: instead of having too many activities , just have a framelayout and change the layout upon that

Comment: You have UI Design for that ?

Comment: Check the date in `onCreate()` and set your content accordingly.

Comment: Look into the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: "How could I do that?": with a few lines of Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create 7 differenet layout for the same activity and use this in your Activity's oncreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Calendar mydate = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dow = mydate.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if(dow == Calendar.SUNDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aa);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.MONDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bb);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.TUESDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cc);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.WEDNESDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dd);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.THURSDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ee);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.FRIDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ff);
    }else if(dow == Calendar.SATURDAY){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gg);
    }
    //..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is vastly different for each weekday, you can have 7 fragments, each for one day, or as Aman suggested, you can have different layout files for popup for UI differences. Select layout / fragment depending on the day of the week.